# TIMESTAMPDIFF between two dates of a table where diff < 1 hour

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to filter out entries whose time is less than 1 hour and additionally within a certain period of time.

table1:

```
id    start                  end                     event

 1. 2018-01-15 10:00:00    2018-01-15 12:00:00     example 1
 2. 2018-12-31 17:00:00    2018-12-31 17:30:00     example 2
```

SQL:

```
SELECT start, end, TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, `start`, `end`)
FROM table1
WHERE  start >="2018-01-01" AND ende <= "2018-12-31
```

In this case I want only select the example 2 entry.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT start, end, TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, start, end) FROM table1 
WHERE start >="2018-01-01" AND ende <= "2018-12-31 AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, start, end) < 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what I have to do if I want to select between TIMESTAMPDIFF > 1 AND < 2 hours?

Comment: You can just change the condition.  
SELECT start, end, TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, start, end) FROM table1 
WHERE start >="2018-01-01" AND ende <= "2018-12-31" AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, start, end) BETWEEN 1 AND 2

Comment: @user9554121 . . . If this answers your question you should consider accepting the answer.